# inserting values to a column from a list using another list as iterator

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am trying to learn python and I came up with a problem. Imagine I have a list called times

```
times = [ 1 , 2, 1, 4]
```

And I want to create a column where the values of my list correspond to the amount of rows I want to insert values. For example Lets say I have another list with names

```
names = [ 'George', 'Sonia','Alice','John']
```

My outcome should me a column like this

```
George
Sonia
Sonia
Alice
John
John
John
John
```

Answer (score 0):

To create column, where the names are repeated X times, you can use [`pd.Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
import pandas as pd


times = [1, 2, 1, 4]
names = ['George', 'Sonia', 'Alice', 'John']

column = pd.Series(names).repeat(times)

print(column)
```

Prints:

```
0    George
1     Sonia
1     Sonia
2     Alice
3      John
3      John
3      John
3      John
dtype: object
```

---

EDIT: Pure python solution:

```
times = [1, 2, 1, 4]
names = ['George', 'Sonia', 'Alice', 'John']

for n, t in zip(names, times):
    for _ in range(t):
        print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
names = [ 'George', 'Sonia','Alice','John'] 
times = [ 1 , 2, 1, 4]

for n, t in zip(names, times):
    print('\n'.join([n] * t))
```

Output:

```
George
Sonia
Sonia
Alice
John
John
John
John
```